# Are the same type variables in struct guaranteed to be in contiguous in memory wothout any padding?

Tags: c++

I am currently working with Vulkan and want to create reliable way to enymerate through all physical device features without needing to call them by name. Currently I am getting pointer to struct and enumerating in loop like in array:

```
VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures Features{};
uint32_t size = sizeof(VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures) / sizeof(VkBool32);
VkBool32* ptr = (VkBool32*)(&Features);
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
  // do something with features
  ptr[i];
}
```

Entire `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures` structure have only `VkBool32` members which are `typedef uint32_t`. Is this guaranteed that if in structure there are many variables listed one after another with the same type they will be contiguous in memory without padding? What if in struct there are some other variables with different types and after them there are many variables with the same type? Example:

```
typedef struct VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan11Features {
    VkStructureType    sType;
    void*              pNext;
    VkBool32           storageBuffer16BitAccess;
    VkBool32           uniformAndStorageBuffer16BitAccess;
    VkBool32           storagePushConstant16;
    VkBool32           storageInputOutput16;
    VkBool32           multiview;
    VkBool32           multiviewGeometryShader;
    VkBool32           multiviewTessellationShader;
    VkBool32           variablePointersStorageBuffer;
    VkBool32           variablePointers;
    VkBool32           protectedMemory;
    VkBool32           samplerYcbcrConversion;
    VkBool32           shaderDrawParameters;
} VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan11Features;
```

Can i use the same approach with enumerating like in array but not starting at beginning but like this

```
VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan11Features Features{};
VkBool32* ptr = (VkBool32*)(&Features.storageBuffer16BitAccess)
```

I am not asking if this approach in code will be readable but if this will be error free, if this will alway work as intended and when enumerating like in array code will always get values from correct memory location?

Comment: NO, the compiler implementation is free to add padding bytes wherever it wants. As this, you code has UB.

Comment: @Klaus: Formally you are right, but if that was the case in practice, then any API that includes structs would be not cross-compiler portable. Which is not the case. Practically there are situations where you won't expect the compiler to add paddings (like in this specific example)

Comment: @valdo: That's a wrong assumption! An API to a pre build library which uses structs must follow a common set of rules which has nothing todo how these rules are. And yes, if one compiler generates different memory layouts for a struct than an other compiler did which was used to build a library, the library want work in that condition. But these rules are existent and followed. So there is no guarantee from the c++ standard but a guarantee that libraries and code using the libs will work, in this case, it will be guaranteed which gaps will be generated on both sides!

Comment: @Klaus: "guarantee that libraries and code using the libs will work" - how is this even possible if you can't predict the struct mem layout by a compiler in the code that's supposed to use the library? You seem to contradict yourself, right?

Comment: @valdo: You have simply to see two sets of rules: One from the c++ language, one from the compiler vendors ( called the ABI ). C++ did not gurantee the layout, but if two compilers guarantee to use the same ABI it will work. Take a look for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not guaranteed that the structure members are continuous in memory. you can enclose the structure definition by #pragma() statements.

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct m_struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    int32_t c; 
} M_STRUCT;
#pragma pack() // restore the default packing
```

In the example above, the structure members packed without padding.

This works only if the processor allows unaligned access.

However, if you use pointers, than the size taken by the pointer depend on the machine's bit size.

Note: Tested with GCC.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that padding is added only if necessary? In my example there is big chunk of variables with the same type and there should not be padding: first `VkBool32` will be aligned to 32 bits and next `VkBool32`s will be placed right after first and automatically padded. And pointers are system dependent but if pointer have type, in my case `VkBool32`, then if incremented , pointer will jump by size of type that it is pointing to in this case increamenting`VkBool32` pointer will move pointer by 4

Comment: In principal yes, but it is not guaranteed if no constraints (#pragma pack() or other compiler switch) are given. In order to write save code it is recommended to avoid such constructs.